# For which values of $k$ is it known that there are infinitely many $n$, such that $2^{n+k}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, congruences

I know that there are no solutions to $2^n\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ for $n>1$ and I can prove that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $2^{n+1}\equiv1\pmod{n}$.
My question is:

> Do we know other fixed values $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
>   $2^{n+k}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ holds *infinitely* often?

Comment: I believe any odd $k$  works, but I don't have a reference nor a proof at hand.

Comment: Any $k\geq 1$ works, see my proof below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For any $k\geq 1$, there are infinitely many solutions of the congruence $2^{n+k}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$. To see this, observe first that there is always a solution $n\geq 1$ satisfying $n+k\geq 7$. Indeed, for $k\geq 6$ this is verified by the trivial solution $n=1$, while for $1\leq k\leq 5$ it is verified by the pairs
$$ (k,n) \ = \ (1,15),\ \ (2,7),\ \ (3,5),\ \ (4,31),\ \ (5,3).$$
Now it suffices to show that, for any fixed $k$ and for any solution $n\geq 1$ satisfying $n+k\geq 7$, there is a bigger solution $n'>n$ for the same $k$. Indeed, let $p$ be a primitive prime divisor of $2^{n+k}-1$, which exists by [Zsigmondy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem). Then, the order of $2$ modulo $p$ equals $n+k$, whence $n+k\mid p-1$. This implies that $pn+k=(p-1)n+(n+k)$ is divisible by $n+k$, hence
$$p,n\mid 2^{n+k}-1\mid 2^{pn+k}-1.$$
However, $p>n+k>n$, so $p$ and $n$ are coprime, and the above implies that $pn\mid 2^{pn+k}-1$. That is, $n'=pn$ is a solution bigger than $n$.

Comment: Very nice proof. My suspicion that it was true only for odd k came from experimentation: for instance for $k=6$, the first is $n=127$, then $n=3263257$, but by pushing further I found a few more.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, this is in fact trivial. For instance if $2^{n+1}\equiv1\pmod{n}$ then
$n$ is of course odd, so $2^{3n+3}\equiv1\pmod{n}$ and mod $3$, so
$2^{3n+3}\equiv1\pmod{3n}$. This probably works for all odd $k$ not only $3$.

Comment: In addition to being odd, $n$ must be co-prime with $3$, right?

Comment: no, wrong. n odd is sufficient $2^2\equiv1\pmod{3}$.

Comment: I certainly agree that $2^2\equiv1\pmod 3$, but if $3\mid n$, then $K\equiv 1\pmod n$ and $K\equiv 1\pmod 3$ do not imply $K\equiv 1\pmod{3n}$ - at least in the absence of other information.

Comment: But it does imply $K^{3} \equiv 1 (\mod 3n)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I see, it does work this way.

Comment: @Robertisrael: my mistake, thanks for correcting